# Bokeh image glyph displays image upside-down

Tags: python, bokeh

Bokeh image glyph shows images upside-down and y-axis does not conform to standards of image display, where tick mark zero starts at the top (matrix-like notation).

```
from scipy.misc import lena
import bokeh.plotting as bp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bp.output_notebook()
%matplotlib inline

lena_img = lena()/256.0

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(lena_img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

f1 = bp.figure(plot_width=512, plot_height=512, 
               x_range=[0, 512], y_range=[0, 512], logo='grey')
f1.image(image=image=[lena_img], x=[0], y=[0], 
         dw=[512], dh=[512], palette='Greys9')
f1.title = 'Lena upside-down'
f1.title_text_color = 'red'
f1.title_text_font_style = 'bold'
bp.show(f1)
```

Is there a solution other than flipping image `lena_img[::-1, :]`? This still leaves y-axis in coordinate system mode.

Comment: It's unfortunate that there is a tension between showing "mathematical" images (which are naturally anchored with a lower left origin) and "image processing" images (which for historical reasons to do with raster scan order are anchored with an upper left origin). For the time being all that could be done was to choose one convention at the expense of the other. You can see what choice was mde. Perhaps we can add some sort of flag to toggle the behavior though. I encourage you to submit a Github issue to discuss it in detail.

Comment: You should be able to set `y_range = [512, 0]` to flip the y-axis range, however.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue with Bokeh image plot.The only thing that worked for me was adding `img=np.flipud(img)` before plotting `img`. Of course you will have to import numpy beforehand.

Hope that helps!

Comment: won't this flip the image?