# How to get bokeh images to plot origin in top left like matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

How can bokeh be used to plot images with the origin in the top left like matplotlib?

I can accomplish this by rotating and transposing the 2d array, but is there a way to do this without modifying the array?  (Modifying the array isn't ideal, because then the axis labels don't match the original data.)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.int8)
img[0][0] = 250 
img[0][1] = 250 
img[0][4] = 500
img[0][3] = 500 
img[1][4] = 500 

output_file("default.html")
plot1 = figure(x_range=(0, img.shape[0]), y_range=(0, img.shape[1]))
plot1.image(image=[img], x=0, y=0, dw=img.shape[0], dh=img.shape[1], palette="Spectral10")
show(plot1)

output_file("rotated_transpose.html")
plot2 = figure(x_range=(0, img.shape[0]), y_range=(0, img.shape[1]))
plot2.image(image=[np.rot90(np.transpose(img))], x=0, y=0, dw=img.shape[0], dh=img.shape[1], palette="Spectral10")
show(plot2)

plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Spectral'), interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I've tried setting the y range in reverse and specifying the axis locations, but this still doesn't match the matplotlib coordinate system:

```
plot3 = figure(x_range=(0, img.shape[0]), y_range=(img.shape[1], 0), x_axis_location='above', y_axis_location='left')
plot3.image(image=[img], x=0, y=0, dw=img.shape[0], dh=img.shape[1], palette="Spectral10")
show(plot3)
```

Comment: This is just toy data, but the actual images I'm plotting are based off medical images where I don't generate the arrays myself; matplot lib displays these images correctly, but bokeh displays the images wrong unless I do a transpose and rotate.

Comment: You're not the only one to hit this problem - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195181/bokeh-image-glyph-displays-image-upside-down).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bokeh image glyph displays image upside-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195181/bokeh-image-glyph-displays-image-upside-down)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue with Bokeh image plot.The only thing that worked for me was adding `img=np.flipud(img)` before plotting img.
Hope that helps !